# How to display global variables when debugging in CLion?

Tags: debug, c++

When I debug my program, the global variables in the program are not displayed. How do I display global variables in the variable window during debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to create a new watcher for global variables from within the variables dashboard when debugging . It should be the plus sign right under the "Variables" tab (CLion 2021.3.3). It's weird that it doesn't show up automatically.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer is actually pretty clear. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4992

The above request implies that at the moment it still is not possible to view global variables. So... One basic workaround would be using stdout until this feature has been added.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack that I use. I create a local variable and assign it to the global variable and this local variable can be seen in the debugger.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using macOS, press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd>, then search you global variable in the prompt window. And then CLion will ask you to add to Watches.(Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

[image]